# react Firestore query nested collection where field then update, or add new doc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently ripping my hair out trying to query a nested collection in my Firestore db.

my db is set up as follows:

```
  users (collection)
    - username
    - displayName
    - ratedItems (collection)
            - itemId
            - timestamp
            - likedItem
```

I want to be able to add/update the rated item  in the ratedItems collection for a specific user but I seem to be hitting 2 problems:

1. I assume the query is incorrect as if(querySnapshot.empty) always returns false even if there are no matching items (matching the itemId) in the ratedItems collection, so it always attempts to add a new item which results in duplicate entries in the collection.
2. if I force the code to bypass the conditional it throws an error when it attempts to update the existing item:

```
Expected type 'mc', but it was: a custom yc object
```

My thoughts are I am using the collectionGroup query incorrectly but I haven't found a solution for this yet. Should I even be using collectionGroup at all?? from what I've read, if I understand correctly this will query ***every*** ratedItem collection regardless of the user, which isn't what I want

```
 const rateItem = async (itemId, liked) => {
    try {
      const itemRef = collection(db, 'users', currentUser.uid, 'ratedItems');
      const q = query(
        collectionGroup(db, 'users', currentUser.uid),
        where('itemId', '==', itemId)
      );
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        await addDoc(itemRef, {
          itemId: itemId,
          timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
          likedItem: liked,
        });
      } else {
        await updateDoc(itemRef, {
          timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
          likedItem: liked,
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume the query is incorrect as if(querySnapshot.empty) always returns false even if there are no matching items (matching the itemId) in the ratedItems collection, so it always attempts to add a new item which results in duplicate entries in the collection.

You used the `itemRef` for both of `addDoc` and `updateDoc` which is not the proper way to do it. You need a correct query syntax in order to [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) your Firestore document.

> if I force the code to bypass the conditional it throws an error when it attempts to update the existing item

You can try the code below to update your nested document:

```
const updateitemRef = query(
    collection(db, 'users', 'user_item', 'ratedItems'), 
    where('itemId', '==', itemId)
);

const itemSnapshot = await getDocs(updateitemRef);

itemSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
// doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots 
    updateDoc(doc.ref, {
        likedItem: liked,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp()          
    });
});
```

For the complete code, you can try the code below:

```
const rateItem = async (itemId, liked) => {
    try {
        const q = query(
            collectionGroup(db, 'users', currentUser.uid),
            where('itemId', '==', itemId)
        );
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

        const additemRef = collection(db, 'users', currentUser.uid, 'ratedItems');

        const updateitemRef = query(
            collection(db, 'users', currentUser.uid, 'ratedItems'), 
            where('itemId', '==', itemId)
        );
        const itemSnapshot = await getDocs(updateitemRef);

        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            await addDoc(additemRef, {
                itemId: itemId,
                likedItem: liked,
                timestamp: serverTimestamp()
            });
        } else {
            itemSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots 
                updateDoc(doc.ref, {
                    likedItem: liked,
                    timestamp: serverTimestamp()          
                });
            });      
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
};
```

---

For more references in creating a query, you can refer to the guides below:

- [Add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)
- [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: Hi RJC, thank you so much for the response. Apologies for my late reply, I've only just got a bit of spare time after work, house cleaning etc.

I implemented what you suggested and the update function now works perfectly, but I still have the issue of not being able to skip over the querySnapshot.empty conditional. For some reason it still hits that code block even if there is no item with that ID listed in the ratedItems collection, so it basically only ever hits the addDoc function. I checked the links for performing queries you posted and it looks okay to me. I'm stumped.

Comment: Just realized what was missing. I had to change the first query back from collectionGroup to collection:

const q = query(
            collectionGroup(db, 'users', currentUser.uid),
            where('itemId', '==', itemId)
        );